# How can I beep without PC speaker

Tags: audio

There is no PC speaker in my laptop. Is there any way to get beeps by a normal speaker in Arch Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing the command

```
beep
```

(try as normal user and as root)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: make sure you have **pcspkr** loaded
`lsmod | grep pcspkr`

Comment: It is loaded : `pcspkr                 16384  0`